# Break a list of job bu person and # of job that person can do a day

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of things to do and want to break it split it out between people and how may things they can do a day.  this data is in 2 tables

so i have 2 tables the first is a list of things to do 
**table 1**

```
task 
-----------
job a 
job b
job c
...
job z
```

**Table 2**  is a list of people and how my things that they can do a day

```
person | date     | amount 
------- -------- ---------- 
Mike    05/23/12 3
Paul    05/23/12 2
Mike    05/24/12 1
Paul    05/24/12 3
...
Mike    06/01/12 6
Paul    06/01/12 9
```

so what i want is get something like

```
Order_id| Person  |date     |task
-------- --------- --------- -----------
1        Mike      05/23/12  job a
2        Mike      05/23/12  job b
3        Mike      05/23/12  job c
4        Paul      05/23/12  job d
5        Paul      05/23/12  Job e
6        Mike      05/24/12  job f
7        Paul      05/24/12  job g
...
26       Mike      06/01/12  job z
```

I have no idea how i would go about this. I am working in Postgres 8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using another table : table3 that has sequence of integers 1 to (max amount), you can query it.

sample of table3

```
seq
-----
1
2
3
4
...
9
10
11
...
```

sample of query

```
select
  sub1.Order_id,
  sub2.Person,
  sub2.date,
  sub1.task
from
(
select
  row_number() over(order by task) as Order_id,
  task
from table1
order by task
) as sub1
inner join
(
select 
  row_number() over(order by table2.date, table2.person) as Order_id,
  table2.person,
  table2.date,
  table2.amount,
  table3.seq
from table2
inner join table3
 on table2.amount >= table3.seq
) as sub2
on sub1.Order_id = sub2.Order_id
```

Note that window functions such as `row_number()` are available since PostgreSQL version 8.4.